# AWS RDS Storage increasing unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-billing

I’m using **RDS PostgreSQL** with the free tier configuration (t2.micro instance, 20 GB of general purpose database storage (SSD) and 20 GB of backups storage).

I’ve created a database with a few tables and the **current usage is below 200 MB**.

The issue is that the **storage has been increasing day by day at a rate of 1 GB per day** since I’ve created the database. As a workaround I’ve tried to stop this behavior by **decreasing the backup retention period from 7 to 0 days**. From yesterday on, no more backups were stored. However, the storage kept on growing at almost the same rate.

I have no clue what's going on and I don't know what to do to stop the consumption and avoid exceeding the free tier storage.

Apart from that, I also don't know which storage is the one that has been increasing (data or backup storage) because the AWS platform only says that the increase is in the RDS Storage (it doesn't distinguish between both types of storages). As I’m not storing a lot of data in the database I suspect the problem is in the backups and snapshots storage and not in the data storage itself.

Thanks in advance!

### Update 2022-09-13

The curious fact is that I have a budget threshold of 8 Gb/month and on the same day every month the threshold is exceeded (in my case, on the 13th of each month). But at the end of the month it kinda resets by itself (it returns to zero). I don't know what is happening. Does anyone know where that temporary Gbs usage comes from?

Comment: What did the AWS helpdesk tell you when you asked them this question?

Comment: Hi! I am unable to ask questions to the AWS tech support because I am still testing AWS, so I have not hired a service support plan yet.
I checked on other people's questions about similar issues in AWS re:Post web but I could not find concrete answers to the problem.

Comment: even on free tier you can view the billing dashboard and see where your costs based on usage are, you will get a clue here. Perhaps disable the automated back ups / snapshots, do you have storage auto-scaling enabled. ?

Comment: Hi! I don't have auto-scaling enabled and the automated backups are disabled as well. I have just added an update in the original question.